# How do I add a lib if I only have .h and .so files?

Tags: c++, linker, static-linking

I have downloaded a library and want to use in my solutions.
I have 2 directories in my library `/include` with all `.h` files and `/lib` with `.so` files.

I have added the /`include` directory to my projects additional include directories and now can include the `.h` files without compiler error. The issue is when I try to use the functionality from `.h` files, it gives me the link error, smth like `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_setopt`

My guess is it doesnt see the definition of the fuinctions in `.so` files. (only guessing here..)

Will much appreciate if someone can help me to resolve me this issue.

Comment: msvc does not use these. The binaries you have are for likely mingw or maybe they are for a different OS.

Comment: You need to link to your .so files

Comment: @AlanBirtles, how?

Comment: Hm, *.so mean shared object, so dynamic linking, but you have the tag static linking. Also you're trying to use a *.so file with the microsoft visual c++ compiler? Something seems weird. But if you are on Windows and have just a *.dll you can extract the exported symbols and generate an import library (usually *.lib)

Comment: You pass the library to your compiler when you are linking, exactly how depends on your compiler and how you're building your code

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I use Visual Studio 2019

Comment: You need curl binaries produced for msvc. It will not link to .so files for mingw or gcc binaries on some other OS.

Comment: Then you need to download your library (I'm presuming libcurl) built for visual studio which will be a dll and/or a lib file